# how to match a sentence between 2 words REGEX

Tags: regex

I need to looking for a sentence between 2 words:

this is my text:

> *hello i am a developer with 2 years of experience hello i am a developer with 4 years of experience*

I need to match the sentence *"i am a developer with 2 years of"* and the other sentence *"i am a developer with 4 years of"*  between *"hello"* and *"experience"*

I need all the sentence that repeats between the same two words... I have tried but I couldnt reach it... any suggestion?

Comment: Hello, what kind of sentence do you want exactly to match? Could you also show what you tried?

Comment: which language?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `(?<=hello ).+?(?=experience)`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tk0gIa/1/)